# useScrollToTop won't work in useEffect? (React Native Expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to scroll to the top of the screen each time useEffect is triggered using the useScrollToTop function. But I get this error when I try to use the function in useEffect:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Here is my code:

```
import { useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Home(...) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    useScrollToTop(ref);
  }, [category])

  return (
    <FlatList 
       ref={ref}
       data={DATA}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       keyExtractor={item => item.approved_site_id}
       numColumns={3} />
  )
}
```

How do I fix this? All I want to do is scroll to the top of the screen in React Native Expo each time useEffect is triggered.

Comment: _"Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"_? - `useScrollToTop` should work without being inside a useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use hook within another hook. `useScrollToTop` is specifically designed to scroll to top during navigation.

I guess what you try to do is scroll to top when category changed, which you try the following

```js
export default function Home(...) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 })
    }
  }, [category])

  return (
    <FlatList 
       ref={ref}
       data={DATA}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       keyExtractor={item => item.approved_site_id}
       numColumns={3} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I get this error: "ref.scrollToTop" is not a function..."ref.scrollToTop is undefined.

Comment: Just fixed my answer. Need to use `ref.current.scrollToTop`

Comment: I get this error: "ref.current.scrollToTop" is not a function..."ref.current.scrollToTop is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking about ScrollView. Try ref.current.scollToIndex(0) Refer to https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex

Comment: I get this error: "scrollToIndex out of range: requested index undefined but maximum is -1

Comment: Haha, my last attempt without opening the react native code: `ref.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 })`. If it still does not work, you can read https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#methods to find the right method. But you get the idea.

Comment: That you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

People looking why useScrollTop isn't working, OP is asking for use with FlatList, if you're using **ScrollView**, use `scrollTo`

```
const scrollViewRef = useRef(null)

const scrollTop = () => {
  if (scrollViewRef.current) {
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true })
  }
}
```

```
<ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>

...

<Button onPress={scrollTop} />
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top/ useScrollToTop is intended to "respond to events from navigation"

Comment: See more on scrollTo https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto